# Cannot start Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

My Outlook 2013 has been working fine for months. Then suddenly today, it won't start.

When I double click on the Outlook 2013 icon, I get a big blue message window with OUTLOOK in the middle and Loading Profile in smaller text in the bottom left hand corner and these dots that scroll horizontally across the blue message window and that's it. Nothing further.

[image: Loading profile]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does the screen ever disappear? Or does it remain on screen? Did you try restarting the machine and trying again? Does Outlook appear in Task Manager

Comment: You can also try and create a new mail profile to identify if it is an issue with your profile.  Create a new mail profile (Just an empty one will do) and then set that to the default.

Comment: If a new profile doesn't help you can also try and disable all add-ins (Take a look at http://www.outlook-apps.com/download/bells-whistles/ that can help)

Comment: @HeXanon, it would be useful if you could explain how the OP can change profiles or disable add-ins without opening Outlook, seeing as that's the problem they're having.

Comment: To create a blank Profile: Open the mail application. Control Panel->Mail (Or Control Panel->User Accounts and Family Safety->Mail). Click on 'Show Profiles'. Click on 'Add'. Type in a name like 'Blank'. Click 'OK'. Click 'Cancel'. Click 'OK'.  At the bottom then select the 'Always use this Profile' option and choose the profile created (Blank). retry and see if there is an issue connecting to mail or with a corrupt profile.

Comment: Thanks @HeXanon, that's actually really helpful in general. You may want to consider putting this down as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Open Control Panel. For Windows Vista, or Windows 7, click the Start button, click Control Panel, click Programs, and then click User Accounts. For Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, type Control Panel while on the Start screen.

Click the Mail icon.

Click Show Profiles.

Click Add.

In the Profile Name box, type a new name for the profile.

Specify the user name, the primary SMPT address, and the password, and then click Next.

You may receive this prompt: Allow this website to configure alias@domain server settings?

In this prompt, click to select the Don’t ask me about this again checkbox, and then click Allow.

In the Add Account dialog, click Finish.

Under Always use this profile, select the profile name that you used in step 5.

Click OK.